Most privacy respecting financial broker?
I intend to invest since a long time. One of my main obstacles hitherto has been the massive amount of personal information the brokers request during sign-on.
I just observed it again with friends, subscribing to various brokers (Interactive Brokers, meesman, swiss quote), even asking questions about your employer...
Hence my question: which is the most privacy respecting broker out there?
Thanks

These questions are required by the regulators. It's part of the KYC procedure and you may not be able to find brokers who don't ask them (and you probably don't want such brokers you do find).

Thanks for your comment!
I'm not sure, one could make such a sweeping statement for the entire world tbh. Different countries likely have different requirements.

You didn't mention any country, usually only people from the US show such arrogance. If you're somewhere else - please tag your question accordingly.


One of my main obstacles hitherto has been the massive amount of
personal information the brokers request during sign-on.
...even asking questions about your employer...
Hence my question: which is the most privacy respecting broker out
there?

You are asking which broker will ask the fewest questions about a customer. The answer is the broker who doesn't follow the law related to where they are regulated.
Most countries require brokers and bankers to collect a minimum amount of verifiable information about their customers. You are either looking for a brokers who doesn't do this., or is located in a jurisdiction that collects little to no information about their customers, and will allow somebody in your location open an account.
Danger. Some of these regulations you are trying to dodge are also designed to protect you, by letting you know that the regulators are watching the brokers.
Your bigger concern should be which brokers and regulators don't protect the data they must collect. Collecting what the law requires, but not protecting the data exposes your finances to risk of fraud.
